# Magnifiing effect over a image with mouse hover with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, magnification, magnify

Is it posibble to achieve this effect just with html and css? In the example image you can see a magnified rounded area (from a higher resolution source picture) where the mouse is hovering. It doesn't to be rounded area or to have borders.

[example of desired Magnifiing effect over a image with mouse hover with HTML/CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kkFN.jpg)

In this [site example](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3) you can see a good example (but it uses jquery and i don't know where to put this code in my web page)

can anyone here give me a clue how to start coding this? (in case that is was doable). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the second example is simple
Only copy the html in your html page, the css in your css page and the jquery code in your html page like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){

var native_width = 0;
var native_height = 0;

//Now the mousemove function
$(".magnify").mousemove(function(e){
    //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
    //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
    //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
    if(!native_width && !native_height)
    {
        //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
        //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
        //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
        //created this image object.
        var image_object = new Image();
        image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

        //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
        //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
        //the image gets loaded.
        native_width = image_object.width;
        native_height = image_object.height;
    }
    else
    {
        //x/y coordinates of the mouse
        //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
        var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
        //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
        //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
        //container(.magnify)
        var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
        var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

        //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
        if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0)
        {
            $(".large").fadeIn(100);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".large").fadeOut(100);
        }
        if($(".large").is(":visible"))
        {
            //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
            //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
            //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
            //large image inside the magnifying glass
            var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*native_width - $(".large").width()/2)*-1;
            var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*native_height - $(".large").height()/2)*-1;
            var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

            //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
            var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
            var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;
            //Now the glass moves with the mouse
            //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
            //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates

            //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
            $(".large").css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
        }
    }
})
```

}

Use this code between  and  in your html page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```